# pip install wheel randomly fails

Tags: python, docker, pip, alpine-linux

I have a python project that I have packaged locally as a wheel, and I want to install this wheel in a virtual environment in a docker container, based off python:alpine3.7. My problem is that sometimes i works, and sometimes it fails to resolve the dependencies in the wheel, seemingly at random.

The dependencies for the wheel is:

```
_install_requires = [
    'numpy>=1.15.0',
    'pandas>=0.21.0',
    'scipy>=1.0.0',
    'scikit-learn>=0.19.2'
]
```

And my dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7

# install dependencies
# the lapack package is only in the community repository
RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk --update add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gcc \
    freetype-dev

RUN apk add --update lapack-dev python py-pip python-dev &&\
    apk add --update linux-headers

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gfortran \
    musl-dev \
    g++ \
    make &&\
    ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install virtualenv

RUN virtualenv -p python3 ./venv

ADD dist/project-as-wheel-py3-none-any.whl .

RUN . ./venv/bin/activate && pip install ./project-as-wheel-py3-none-any.whl
```

When building the docker container, sometimes it fails, with a typical log being:

```
Processing /project-as-wheel-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.19.2 (from project-as-wheel==0.2.6)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/b6/454cf208be93efa3db50ce06b732328c57ede005d1dcfa71d9a1548530b0/scikit-learn-0.19.2.tar.gz (9.7MB)
Collecting pandas>=0.21.0 (from project-as-wheel==0.2.6)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/56/82c4d4c049294f87ebd05b65fdcbc9ed68bd23fb0a7e4469caf9a75d199f/pandas-0.23.3.tar.gz (10.5MB)
Collecting numpy>=1.15.0 (from project-as-wheel==0.2.6)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/20/c81632328b1a4e1db65f45c0a1350a9c5341fd4bbb8ea66cdd98da56fe2e/numpy-1.15.0.zip (4.5MB)
Collecting scipy>=1.0.0 (from project-as-wheel==0.2.6)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/76/7e844757b9f3bf5ab9f951ccd3e4a8eed91ab8720b0aac8c2adcc2fdae9f/scipy-1.1.0.tar.gz (15.6MB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas>=0.21.0->project-as-wheel==0.2.6)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (211kB)
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas>=0.21.0->project-as-wheel==0.2.6)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/4e/27c34b62430286c6d59177a0842ed90dc789ce5d1ed740887653b898779a/pytz-2018.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas>=0.21.0->project-as-wheel==0.2.6)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn, pandas, numpy, scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scikit-learn: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scikit-learn: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ogmdp3dv --python-tag cp37:
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 168, in get_numpy_status
      import numpy
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 148, in get_scipy_status
      import scipy
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 269, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 249, in setup_package
      .format(numpy_req_str, instructions))
  ImportError: Numerical Python (NumPy) is not installed.
  scikit-learn requires NumPy >= 1.8.2.
  Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html    


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
  Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8d/e7/58/7a882c73419e95e6709d925abb4b56c719c9be59ef826fe01c
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/77/d2/00/03180c22fc40b6f17f6a5c6ea0fa1689734a9cf4cf54179a1c
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-83ktidr8 --python-tag cp37:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scipy/setup.py", line 474, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scipy/setup.py", line 450, in setup_package
      from numpy.distutils.core import setup
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'    

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  Complete output from command /venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:    

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:    

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)    

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).    


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Successfully built pandas numpy
Failed to build scikit-learn scipy
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn, six, python-dateutil, pytz, numpy, pandas, scipy, project-as-wheel
  Running setup.py install for scikit-learn: started
    Running setup.py install for scikit-learn: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-dwajrs1d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /venv/include/site/python3.7/scikit-learn:
    Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 168, in get_numpy_status
        import numpy
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 148, in get_scipy_status
        import scipy
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 269, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 249, in setup_package
        .format(numpy_req_str, instructions))
    ImportError: Numerical Python (NumPy) is not installed.
    scikit-learn requires NumPy >= 1.8.2.
    Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html    


    ----------------------------------------
Command "/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-dwajrs1d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /venv/include/site/python3.7/scikit-learn" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-439jjmrz/scikit-learn/
```

What confuses me is that pip manages to install numpy and pandas, then fails to install scipy claiming there's "No module named 'numpy'".

Edit: A TL;DR on the log is:

1. pip tries to install scikit-learn, fails as numpy is not installed.
2. pip tries to install pandas, succeeds.
3. pip tries to install numpy, succeeds.
4. pip tries to install scipy, fail as numpy is not installed (however it was successfully installed in step 3 above!).
5. pip declares that it succeeded in installing pandas and numpy, but failed to install scikit-learn and scipy.
6. pip tries again to install scipy, fails again, complaining that numpy is not installed.
7. pip gives up.

Edit2: Based on Nuts suggestion I changed the relevant line in the dockerfile to

```
RUN . ./venv/bin/activate && pip install numpy && pip install scipy && pip install ./project-as-wheel-py3-none-any.whl
```

Not very satisfactory, as I can't get the version requirements out of setup.py, but it works.

Comment: It does not install `numpy` before `scikit-learn`. Thats why it fails

Comment: It does install numpy, and later scipy fails to install, complaining that numpy isn't installed, see my edit at the bottom.

Comment: Try to add numpy to setup_requirement. More info at this issue: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7867

Comment: Thanks, that explains it (kind of, can't say I fully understand). Manually installing numpy and scipy before the wheel works.

Answer (score 1):

Change requirements to this

```
_install_requires = [
    'numpy>= 1.8.2',
    'pandas>=0.21.0',
    'scipy>=1.0.0',
    'scikit-learn>=0.19.2'
]
```