# installing scikit-learn Docker image problem

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, dockerfile, docker-image

im trying to install scikit-learn with docker image! its failed and here is the error:

`ImportError: Numerical Python (NumPy) is not installed.
  scikit-learn requires NumPy >= 1.8.2.
  Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html
Failed building wheel for scikit-learn`

but in logs just before of scikit-learn pip trying to isntall numpy==1.9.0 and log says its DONE, I even try to install with :

`scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.19.1`

but nothing is changed! same error

my hole docker image is working well without scikit-learn, my app is running except the scikit-learn parts!

I tried  to change the version and install the last version:

`scikit-learn[alldeps]`

and its ok but I have some incompatibility in my application I need to use the 0.19.1 version, not 0.19.2!

ps: my requirements.txt file is working in my python3 venv (mac and ubuntu)!!!

Comment: another question has the same issue, I think it's up to sciket-learn pip repository  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657805/pip-install-wheel-randomly-fails

Comment: which version of python you are trying with and upload Dockerfile as well for reference.

Comment: FROM python:3 ! version 3

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but faced a similar issue with `heroku` (they also use linux environments). What you have to do is check the version of your local/dev environment and use that specific versions while deploying, even the python version.

```
import scipy
import sklearn
import numpy

print(scipy.__version__)
print(sklearn.__version__)
print(numpy.__version__)
```

Add this versions specifically to `requirements.txt`

```
scipy==1.4.1
scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
numpy==1.19.5
```

In `heroku` to [set the Python runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes), add a `runtime.txt` file to your app’s root directory that declares the exact version number to use:

```
python-3.7.10
```